# Postgresql unique constraint mystery that does not seem to work with batch inserts

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

I have a table with a unique constraint over 5 columns, all nullable=false.  These columns are varchar(30), varchar, 3 float8 columns.   There is an autoincrement id column, but that is not included in the constraint.

Often times I have duplicates and so my query has "...on conflict do nothing".  I have seen a batch insert of rows I that I to know have all duplicates, and so I expect to have 0 affected rows.  Instead I have some dupes inserted (From what i have seen it's about 5-15%, it's not constant).

After this, I queried the table with a select distinct across only all columns in the constraint, and postgres will returned the duplicate rows with duplicate values.  Same goes for a select query with GROUP BY on all columns in the constraint. I expect the dupe rows to collapse into one, but instead I see both duplicate rows returned to me.

However, when I manually delete one of the two duplicate rows, and then try to insert the single duplicate row then postgresql will rightly tell me there is a conflict and i wont be able to insert.

Am I missing something?  My code is now adjusted to insert rows one by one, but of course that is a lot less efficient.

Comment: maybe the rows are not really duplicates? Maybe there are spaces for example in the values of varchar columns? "TEST" <> "TEST  "

Comment: And what about these floats? Are you 100% sure all 3 have exactly the same content in all duplicate rows? And why using a float at all, because it might be fast and compact, it's a notorious cause of unexpected results. And could you share some of the duplicate rows?

Comment: Please post a [mre]. Perhaps best in a fiddle. See [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/) and/or [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it is a bug in postgres actually.  I am using 11.6

A friend of mine suggested it might be a corrupted index.  i created a cloned table with the same unique index, and i did

```
insert into ectrades2 select * from ectrades;
```

this still allowed the dupes to be entered so that's likely not the case.  I then tried the same thing but wrote a short program to make individual inserts, and there is a rowcount difference so at least some rows are being filtered, but i cannot confirm all of them are at the moment. i'd have to write another program to do so.  the table has almost a billion rows

Answer (score 1):

Your experiments with `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` prove that the rows are not really identical. I can think of two causes:

1. The `double precision` columns are not really identical. It is always very problematic to perform equality comparisons on floating point numbers.

   ```
   SELECT 500::float8 / 3::float8, 5::float8 / 3::float8 * 100::float8;

         ?column?      │      ?column?      
   ════════════════════╪════════════════════
    166.66666666666666 │ 166.66666666666669
   (1 row)
   ```
2. Some of the strings look equal, but aren't. Popular examples are   (space) and   (no-break space), `M` (ASCII letter) and `Μ` (Greek upper case letter Mu) or `ä` (a diaeresis) and `ä` (a and combining diaeresis—two code points that together form a character).

   To investigate that problem, look at the bytes that make up the string:

   ```
   SELECT convert_to('ä', 'UTF8'), convert_to('ä', 'UTF8');

    convert_to │ convert_to 
   ════════════╪════════════
    \xc3a4     │ \x61cc88
   (1 row)
   ```

My money is on 2.

Comment: they should be exactly equal, because the program that i have reads from redis where values are strings, and then creates a sql string to insert into PG.  so the sql insert statement would have the exact values.  i cant set float digits to 3 because i need the full precision 17 decimal places

what do you mean by "look" identical but not really?  I viewed one set of dupes and the floating point numbers went to 12 or 15 places but they matched each other. i checked for empty spaces in strings as well but could not find any. again it's from the same data in redis.

Comment: Forget about `extra_float_digits`, I remembered the different meaning in PostgreSQL v11. I changed my opinion on the likely cause and added some examples that might help you identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [`quote_literal()`, `ascii()`, `md5()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), [`sha256(v::bytea)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-OTHER) when you inspect text values: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/BucKv4wD)

   ```sql
   select v,quote_literal(v),ascii(v),md5(v),sha256(v::bytea) 
   from (values 
     (''   ),
     (' '  ),
     (E'\t')) AS _(v);
   ```

   | v | quote_literal | ascii | md5 | sha256 |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   |  | '' | 0 | d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e | \xe3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855 |
   |  | ' ' | 32 | 7215ee9c7d9dc229d2921a40e899ec5f | \x36a9e7f1c95b82ffb99743e0c5c4ce95d83c9a430aac59f84ef3cbfab6145068 |
   |  | ' ' | 9 | 5e732a1878be2342dbfeff5fe3ca5aa3 | \x2b4c342f5433ebe591a1da77e013d1b72475562d48578dca8b84bac6651c3cb9 |

   You can explode them and compare character by character: note the [Cyrillic `с`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Es_(Cyrillic)):

   ```sql
   select a.n, 
          a.a, ascii(a.a), 
          b.b, ascii(b.b), 
          a.a=b.b is_equal
   from string_to_table(E'äbc\t  ',null) with ordinality as a(a,n) full outer join 
        string_to_table(E'äbс  \r',null) with ordinality as b(b,n) on a.n=b.n;
   ```

   | n | a | ascii | b | ascii | is_equal |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | a | 97 | ä | 228 | f |
   | 2 | ̈ | 776 | b | 98 | f |
   | 3 | b | 98 | с | 1089 | f |
   | 4 | c | 99 |  | 32 | f |
   | 5 |  | 9 |  | 32 | f |
   | 6 |  | 32 |  | 13 | f |
   | 7 |  | 32 | *null* | *null* | *null* |
2. Make sure your [floats](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) are equal all the way. Some clients can round outputs by default, hiding the difference. Some operations look like they should result in the same float, but [they don't](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/). Still, once saved to db and inspected, they should present differently if they aren't equal.

   ```sql
   select a.n, a.a, b.b, a.a=b.b is_equal
   from string_to_table((5419351/1725033::float8)::text,null) with ordinality as a(a,n)
   full outer join string_to_table(pi()::text,null) with ordinality as b(b,n)
   on a.n=b.n;
   ```

   | n | a | b | is_equal |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 1 | 3 | 3 | t |
   | 2 | . | . | t |
   | 3 | 1 | 1 | t |
   | 4 | 4 | 4 | t |
   | ... | ... | ... | ... |
   | 14 | 9 | 9 | t |
   | 15 | **8** | **7** | **F** |
   | 16 | **1** | **9** | **F** |
   | 17 | **5** | **3** | **F** |
   | 18 | **3** | ***null*** | ***null*** |
3. You haven't shared your DDL so it's a shot in the dark, but people sometimes confuse what's meant to be unique according to their definition:

   ```sql
   create table t1 (a text not null unique, b text not null unique);
   create table t2 (a text not null, b text not null, unique (a,b));
   ```

   `t1` forces both columns to be *individually* unique. `t2` only makes sure their *combinations* are unique. This means `t2` accepts `('x','y')`, `('x','z')` at the same time: they share the value in column `a`, but as a combination of two values, each is unique. `t1` would detect that `x` is already present and reject the second row.
4. Similar to 3: you could have `null` differentiators. Unless all columns guarded by your unique constraint are `not null`, it's enough for one of them to be `null` for a duplicate to sneak through. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/jyyU0apW):

   ```sql
   create table t1 (a text unique, b text unique);
   create table t2 (a text, b text, unique (a,b));
   insert into t1 values ('x','y'),
                         (null,null),(null,null);
   --t2 accepts both (x,y) and (x,z), because even though `a` alone isn't unique, 
   --the `(a,b)` combination as a whole is unique
   insert into t2 values ('x','y'),('x','z'),
                         ('x',null),('x',null),
                         (null,'y'),(null,'y');
   --t1 already rejects anything with an 'x' in column `a`
   insert into t1 values ('x','z');
   ```

   > ```
   > ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "t1_a_key"
   > DETAIL:  Key (a)=(x) already exists.
   > ```

   ```sql
   table t1;
   ```

   | a | b |
   | --- | --- |
   | x | y |
   | *null* | *null* |
   | *null* | *null* |

   ```sql
   table t2;
   ```

   | a | b |
   | --- | --- |
   | x | y |
   | x | z |
   | x | *null* |
   | x | *null* |
   | *null* | y |
   | *null* | y |
5. If those really are duplicates, clean them up and [`reindex table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-reindex.html) in case you have a corrupted index.

Comment: can you expand on corrupted indices?  i did experience in another table something strange where a unique constraint was said to be violated during an insert, however such a row didn't exist.

Comment: Here's [Craig Ringer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/108530/242866) with a nice list, [Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Corruption), some example release notes [1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14-1.html#id-1.11.6.13.5), [2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14-2.html), [3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/release-12-6.html) fixing a rare bug leading to them. Note the order of my remarks: the first two are way, way more likely than the last one. In the rare case of index corruption, that's still not necessarily how it would manifest itself.